# How to use single top in android navigation

Tags: android, android-navigation

I'm building a bottom navigation bar with two menu(1,2) and twofragments, where activity holds a bottom menu and a navhost fragment with navgraph
Here is the required workflow,  (exactly like current updated mobile Facebook app)

activity starts with fargment1, user browses list of item on recycle view

When recyle view item is on 15th item on fragment1, user presses menuitem2, fragment2 displayed, where is again browseres different list of items on recycleview.

when user presses back button or menuitem1, fragment1 should resume from 15th item.

from menu1 when user presses menu2, fragment2 should resume from left item.

Here is how i coded it,

Navigation frag1 to frag2, popbehaviour:frag1;inclusive:false, singletop: true

Navigation frag2 to frag1, popbehaviour:frag1;inclusive:false, singletop: true

so what is happening is when i try to press menu1 from menu2, this pop behaviour is creating new frag1 instance and deletes the old frag1 instance as the singletp is set true.

if i remove single top many instance are created
when pressed backbutton from menu2, it worked as intended

how to set popbehaviour and singletop for my  required behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
  fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,fragment1, "1").commit();
```

And

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                active = fragment1;
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                active = fragment2;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any solution through navgraph instead of using fragment manager? bacause my navhost fragment is linked to navgraph